# jQuery validation custom method rule and message with dynamic name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a validation rule that I want to add using a variable varFunctionID, which represents a custom validation method. Rather than looking for the value of the variable, it searches for a function called varFunctionID, which does not exist. How can I ensure that the value, not the name, of the variable is used?  Also, I cannot use the name in place of the variable.

```
var varFunctionID = "nameOfMyCustomValidationFunction";

$('#myField').rules('add', {
    varFunctionID: true
    },
    messages: {
        varFunctionID: "My message."
    }
});
```

*** EDIT ***
There is no way to make the name dynamic.  The way to handle such a need is to pass in a parameter to the validation method, like so:

```
$('#myField').rules('add', {
    myFunction: { myParm: "parm" }
    },
    messages: {
        myFunction: "My message."
    }
});

jQuery.validator.addMethod("myFunction", function (value, element, options) {
            var passParm= options.myParm;
});
```

Comment: You're not allowed to post the same question more than once.  Please decide which one to delete.  Otherwise, this later one will be closed as the duplicate.  Thanks.

Comment: You cannot do what you're asking.  You need to use the actual name of your custom method.  As this question is written, it's entirely unclear why you can't use the actual name of the custom method in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I want to close the other one, but I do not see an option to do so.  After much digging, this does not appear to be possible or viable.  I have instead found out how to pass a parameter to the validation method, eliminating the need for it to be dynamic.

Comment: Since this question was easier to understand, I closed your other one as the duplicate.  However, you as the OP, should also see a "delete" link.  Might not be a bad idea to do that if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you would need to do such a thing.  As your OP is written,  it's entirely unclear why you can't use the actual name of the custom method in the first place.

**You cannot do what you're asking**. You would need to use the *actual* name of your custom method within the `.rules()` method.

---

**EDIT**:  My previously suggested workaround is not viable.

The custom method is not meant to have a "dynamic" name and I'm not sure why the name would ever need to be dynamic.  The custom method is created and you either assign it to one or more fields or don't.  Anything "dynamic" about this function would be taken care of by passing in custom parameters.

[See `.addMethod()` method documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/).

Comment: This is correct.  Passing a parameter to the validation method removes the need for the name to be dynamic.